# Using loopbacks and null-sink cause extreme distortion after 20-30s during ffmpeg recording

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, alsa, pulse-audio

I'm trying to record both video, speaker sounds and microphone sounds at the same time. To deal with the audio, I set up two **loopbacks** (one for microphone, one for speakers):

```
pactl load-module module-loopback
pactl load-module module-loopback
```

Using `pavucontrol`, I redirect both loopbacks to a **null-sink**, which is the audio input for my ffmpeg recording script:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink
pavucontrol
```

I then start recording with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -y -r 60 -f alsa -i pulse output.mkv
```

Everything seems to work perfectly, for the first 20-25 seconds of `output.mkv`. After that, sound becomes horribly distorted until the end of the file. [Here's a similar report from another user.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=147060)

**Is there a way to fix/avoid the distortion?**

**Or, is there an alternative way to record both microphone and speakers at the same time (that doesn't cause distortion)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are utilities that will do all the work for you.

**Kazam**

See the article [Record Desktop With Both Speaker And Microphone Audio On Linux/Ubuntu](http://www.funtechtips.com/2013/08/record-desktop-with-both-speaker-and-microphone-audio-on-linuxubuntu/).

[**Tibesti**](https://launchpad.net/tibesti)

See the article [Tibesti screencasting tool for Linux](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/tibesti-screencasting-app-for-linux).

[**recordMyDesktop**](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php)

See the article [Record Screen Activity in Ubuntu with RecordMyDesktop](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24742/record-screen-activity-in-ubuntu-with-recordmydesktop/).
This product seems to require [more fiddling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/how-can-i-record-the-sound-output-with-gtk-recordmydesktop).